# Did the EU prohibit the transport of Russian fertilizer to non-EU countries, so that only the EU could purchase it?

Tags: russia, europe, trade

[Reportedly](https://www.siasat.com/russia-ready-to-give-fertilisers-to-poor-nations-for-free-putin-2414580/)  Russia’s permanent representative to the UN, Vassily Nebenzia

> accused EU officials of “selfishness, cynicism and hypocrisy” for prohibiting European carriers from transporting Russian fertilisers to Africa, Asia or Latin America, while allowing deliveries to EU countries, RT reported.

Likewise

> “It turns out that only they [the EU] could purchase our fertilisers. What about the developing countries, the poorest countries of the world,” [Putin] asked.

Did the EU do that, i.e. prohibit exports of Russian fertilizer via EU carriers to Africa etc., while importing Russian fertilizer to the EU?

Comment: It seems [there are](https://eng.lsm.lv/article/economy/transport/ship-stuck-in-gulf-of-riga-since-march-due-to-sanctions.a473235/) some shipments belonging to specific, sanctioned oligarchs that have been stuck since the spring, but the EU themselves can't seem to buy those shipments either. So, the remaining question seems to be whether the non-sanctioned Russian sellers can sell fertilizer through the EU [carriers] to other places.

Comment: Looks it might be true in part as there is apparently an insurance ban on shipping "certain fertilizers" https://www.bnnbloomberg.ca/scope-of-eu-ban-on-russian-coal-and-fertilizers-jolts-insurers-1.1805935 ... although the details are patchy in that piece. If the list of fertilizers that are banned from “purchase” vs “transfer” are different the claim might have legs. Also "The import into the EU of set quota-based volumes of certain Russian fertilizers is permitted."

Comment: OTOH judging from [this EU FAQ](https://ec.europa.eu/info/files/faqs-sanctions-russia-listed-goods_en) it doesn't seem that the lists would be different.